# Idiom for "doing an entire team's job alone"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom for saying something like:

- I did an entire team's job all by myself.
- He did a job which usually a team of specialists would be required to do that.
- ...

Comment: *A one-man band*: an organization in which one person does all the work or has all the power. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+one-man+band

Comment: A [one man team](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=one-man%20team) seems to fit.

Comment: You did it single handedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did an entire team's job all by myself.

Options:

> *I **carried the team's load** on that job*
>
> *I  **carried the team's weight** on that job.*

and

> He did a job which usually a team of specialists would be required to do

maybe:

> He c**arried the load of a team** of specialists on that job,

*carry the load [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/carry-the-load)*

Other possibilities: *I **held the team up** on that job*
 *He **bore the load** of a team of specialists*

I **sustained** the team on that job,
  He **sustained the weight** of a team